# How to run Python script in PHP with getting values

Tags: php, python, variables

I would like to run a `Python` script from a `PHP` script so that it can get the values ​​and write them out.

For example:

```
{ "temperature": 21, "pressure":962 }
```

This is my Python script and I would like to get these two variables (temperature, pressure):

```
import smbus
import time
import sys

bus = smbus.SMBus(1) 
i=0

for i in range(1): # pętla
    bus.write_byte_data(0x5d, 0x20, 0b10000000)
    bus.write_byte_data(0x5d, 0x21, 0b1) 
    Temp_LSB = bus.read_byte_data(0x5d, 0x2b)
    Temp_MSB = bus.read_byte_data(0x5d, 0x2c)

    count = (Temp_MSB << 8) + Temp_LSB 
    if (count >= 0x8000):              
        count1 = -((65535-count) + 1)
    else:
        count1 = count

    temperature = 42.5 + (count1/480.0)
    print"temperature = ",temperature
    ph=bus.read_byte_data(0x5d, 0x2a)
    pl = bus.read_byte_data(0x5d, 0x29)
    pxl=bus.read_byte_data(0x5d, 0x28)
    #print'PressOut_XL = ',pxl
    pressure=float((((ph<<8)+pl)<<8)+pxl)
    print "pressure = ",pressure
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This is my php script:

```
<?php

$result = exec('python /home/pi/test/test.py', $output, $retval);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($retval);

?>
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Stupid question .. Does your `php` installation have `exec` permissions by the server?  And what (if any) errors are you receiving?

Comment: @Zak Would you like to rephrase your comment? Currently it is begging for "rude" flags.

Comment: I rephrase .. "I have a stupid question for you"  -- Not "Your question is stupid"  -- Sorry for the confusion ..

Comment: It's ok I've already found a solution. I did not realize I had to give rights to my script and python-smbus.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting errors in your `.py` script. In that case you want to redirect your `STDERR` to `STDOUT`.

Try the script below:

```
exec('python /home/pi/test/test.py 2>&1', $output, $retval);
```